# Check if an event already exists

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a data grid loading row event

```
_gridObj.LoadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(_gridObj_LoadingRow);
```

and in the handler I am creating another event. In the following code how can I know if the MouseLeftBtn event already exists for that row?

```
void _gridObj_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseLeftButtonUp);
}
```

Thanks,

Voodoo

Comment: Do you want to test that an event handler is attached so you don't attach more than one event? i.e the LoadingRow event might get fired more than once per row?

Comment: Yes, in the `_gridObj_LoadingRow` the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event is attached multiple times. I want to check whether the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event is already attached so I don't register another event for it. It is firing the `MouseLeftButtonUp` multiple times in my case here.

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer which should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on your comment that you don't want to attach muliple handlers in this case I unsubscribe then resubscribe. It does not give an error unsubscribing if none exists and ensures only one handler.

```
void _gridObj_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MouseLeftButtonUp -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    e.Row.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseLeftButtonUp);
}
```